# Pushing to github issue

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, push

I have a project which was bound to the remote server on github, but somehow it stopped working, so I deleted the remote origin folder through the Organizer and reconnected fresh.

But now, I have changes made to the project that are not yet pushed to the remote server.
I am trying to push, and I get the error:"Your working copy is out of date. Try pulling from the remote to get the latest changes, then push again.".
But this is not what I want to do, because it will erase all my local changes!
Actually, the error message is incorrect, because my working copy is newer than the version on the remote.

Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: did you try pushing with the -f option?

Comment: Also did you try first to change the remote URL to your git (git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here) ?

Comment: I am pushing through the Xcode. Danypata, what do you mean? I have added a remote through the Organizer and now trying to push to it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AnatolyAnatoly, I don't know the Xcode equivalent for this url update but I think you can do it also from terminal if you navigate to the folder where your project is located. I used this command several times when the remote git repo was changed/moved to another server. This command will tell your git that the repo is changed to another location and the files/changes should be pushed to the new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I forget to pull, git does not overwrite my local changes.

Still it is worth being safe. Store your local commits as a stash, then pull and apply the stash.

See this stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414769/git-pull-keeping-local-changes):

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```