# Keeping local changes in git while pulling from remote

Tags: git, github

Say I am working on a shared repo. In that repo is a `defaults.js` file that specifies various URLs. When I clone the repo locally, I change some of these URLs to point at services that are running locally. How can I keep these URLs set to the local values, while pulling new updates from remote?

So far I have been happily (naively?) using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414769/git-pull-keeping-local-changes)

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

but while trying this today I received a

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in config/defaults.js

Since we rebase rather than merge, I didn't want to start creating messy merges, particularly for something so trivial. So I just reset, got rid of my changes so local mirrored remote, and then manually changed the URLs again. Obviously, I don't want to keep doing this, what is the preferred approach?

The solution in the link above says to simply

```
git checkout --theirs -- defaults.js
```

because you know that what you put in the stash is what you want. But that's not true in my case, I do want a merge of mine and theirs, without actually merging.

Comment: Are you looking for a *git only* solution? maybe it is possible to have an untracked local.js that overrides the URLs you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're maintaining a different state than `origin` that you don't want committed, you're going to run into conflicts like this, and the things you're already trying are pretty much the simplest ways to fix it.

There are a couple cleaner ways to solves this for good that avoid futzing with Git:

1. If you can use environment variables, set up `defaults.js` to prefer those and fall back to another default contained in the file. Then you can set your local ENV differently than your coworkers or production.
2. Set up a `local-defaults.js` file that's preferred over `defaults.js` (either wholesale or by merging options), and add it to `.gitignore` so it's not committed. Then everyone can keep their own file with whichever overrides they need.

Both of these are a code change - effectively a new feature - but as your team size grows everyone will be happy they have proper customization available without having to fight through the `stash` dance.